# PHP : is there any function works like xmlrpc_encode_request?

Tags: php

I've been writing free php script

when i finished unfortunately i found that xmlrpc_encode_request not work in some hosting

is there a way to active it direct without editing php.ini ? or is there any function works  like xmlrpc_encode_request without edit php.ini?

Any help would be much appreciated.

EX:

```
<?php
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("method", array(1, 2, 3));
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'header' => "Content-Type: text/xml",
    'content' => $request
)));
$file = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/xmlrpc", false, $context);
$response = xmlrpc_decode($file);
if ($response && xmlrpc_is_fault($response)) {
    trigger_error("xmlrpc: $response[faultString] ($response[faultCode])");
} else {
    print_r($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you can include? More details regarding the failure of your code to work (error messages, etc.) would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

This has been implemented in the [XML_RPC2](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_RPC2) package. Here's an example:

```
require_once 'XML/RPC2/Backend/Php/Request.php';

$request = new XML_RPC2_Backend_Php_Request('method', 'utf-8');
$request->setParameters(array(1, 2, 3));

$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'header' => "Content-Type: text/xml",
    'content' => $request->encode(),
)));
```

However, it would be easier to use their client as well:

```
require_once 'XML/RPC2/Client.php';

$client = XML_RPC2_Client::create('http://example.org/xmlrpc');
$response = $client->method(1, 2, 3);
```